# Convolutional layer in tensorflow: stride vs tf.gather

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, backpropagation, stride

I implemented a convolutional neural network in TensorFlow. However, instead of using the stride operator for the convolutional layers, I use tf.gather to pick every second element. Using this implementation I receive **significantly worse** results on cifar10 compared to the usual strides operator. Does somebody have an idea, how this can happen?

So basically what I do is:

> input -> convolution -> custom_stride_operation -> convolution -> etc

and I compare this to:

> Input -> convolution (with stride 2) -> convolution (with stride 2) ->
> etc

I use the following code as a replacement for the stride operation on a tensor x of shape (batch,height,width,channels):

```
i = tf.range(0,height//2,dtype=tf.int32)*2
i = tf.expand_dims(i,axis=0)
i = tf.repeat(i,tf.shape(input)[0],axis=0)

x = tf.gather(x, i, axis=1,batch_dims=1)
x = tf.gather(x, i, axis=2,batch_dims=1)
```

Comment: I believe they are doing fundamentally different things. stride controls the step size for the convolution, but the output value is still obtained by multipling the inputs by the kernel. Using tf.gather, the output is instead simply a selected set of elements from the input. There are no learned parameters

Comment: are you instead referring to `tf.strided_slice()` or `tf.slice()`?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, that part wasn't clear. I first perform a convolution (without stride) and THEN I use my custom stride. I will edit the question